# How did Jacob know what law enforcement was after Seth and Richie?

Tags: plot-explanation, from-dusk-till-dawn

In [*From Dusk Till Dawn*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116367/), Jacob attempts to calm  Seth by explaining to him that he has eluded law enforcement after crossing the border into Mexico:

> The entire state of Texas, along with the FBI are looking for you. 
>   Did they find you?  No, they couldn't.  You've won, Seth.  Enjoy it.

I don't recall Seth or Richie saying anything to Jacob about how many or the type of law enforcement that is searching for them.  **How did Jacob know that law enforcement from Texas and the FBI were pursuing Seth and Richie?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He may have just assumed it the FBI were involved based on the fact that the Gecko's had robbed a bank.

Clearly the brothers are on the run from 'regular' law enforcement but Seth [**tells/asks**](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/from_dusk_till_dawk.html) Jacob

> Now, stop me if I'm wrong, but I take it you don't give a shit about seeing me and my brother receiving justice, or **the bank getting its money back**. Right now all you care about is the safety of your daughter, your son and possibly yourself. Am I correct?

[**FBI.gov**](https://www.fbi.gov/investigate/violent-crime/bank-robbery)

> The FBI has had a primary role in bank robbery investigations since the 1930s, when John Dillinger and his gang were robbing banks and capturing the public’s imagination. In 1934, it became a federal crime to rob any national bank or state member bank of the Federal Reserve System. The law soon expanded to include bank burglary, larceny, and similar crimes, with jurisdiction delegated to the FBI. Today the Bureau, while continuing to provide assistance to state and local partners investigating bank robberies, focuses its investigative resources on those suspects who post the greatest safety threats to the public, including the most violent and/or the most prolific serial offenders who often cross jurisdictional boundaries.